# Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a){return new j(a)} has no method 'has'

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am getting this error. I am noob and could not find a satisfied answer.
This is an example that I am working on. I looked into many question concerning the same type, but I could not make anything of it. It would be nice if the you answer in a descriptive way.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>hello-backbonejs</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.1.6/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.0/backbone-min.js"></script>

    <script src="1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

//and javascript is here ..... name "1.js"

```
(function($){
     var ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
     el: $('body'), // el attache`enter code here`s to existing element

        events: {
      'click button#add': 'addItem'
    },
    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'addItem'); // every function that uses 'this' as the current object should be in here

      this.counter = 0; // total number of items added thus far
      this.render();
    },

        render: function(){
      $(this.el).append("<button id='add'>Add list item</button>");
      $(this.el).append("<ul></ul>");
    }, addItem: function(){
      this.counter++;
      $('ul', this.el).append("<li>hello world"+this.counter+"</li>");
    }
  });

  var listView = new ListView();
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/jm8gr/1/

Comment: the error is with the library that I am using. I think it is not compatibale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.0/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

Reason

1. use jquery 1.9.1 instead of 1.9
2. use underscore 1.5.0